# Using external modules when applying custom functions in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The following snippet tries to apply a simple function to a PySpark RDD object:

```
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors', 5)
sc = SparkContext(appName="tmp", conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel('WARN')

fn = 'my_csv_file'
rdd = sc.textFile(fn)
rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
header = rdd.first()
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda line:line != header)
def parse_line(line):
    ret = pyspark.Row(**{h:line[i] for (i, h) in enumerate(header)})
    return ret
rows = rdd.map(lambda line: parse_line(line))
sdf = rows.toDF()
```

If I start the program with `python my_snippet.py`, it fails by complaining that :

```
File "<ipython-input-27-8e46d56b2984>", line 6, in <lambda>
File "<ipython-input-27-8e46d56b2984>", line 3, in parse_line
NameError: global name 'pyspark' is not defined
```

I replaced the `parse_line` function to the following:

```
def parse_line(line):
    ret = h:line[i] for (i, h) in enumerate(header)
    ret['dir'] = dir()
    return ret
```

Now, the dataframe is created and the `dir` column shows that the namespace inside
the function contains only two objects: `line` and `ret`. How can I have other modules and object as the part of the function? 
Not only pyspark but others too.

**EDIT** Note, that pyspark is available within the program. Only if the function is called by `map` (and, I assume `filter`, `reduce` and others), it doesn't see any imported modules.

Comment: Does the following answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Answer to the original question:
It seems like the source of the problem is running **python my_snippet.py**
You should execute your code using **spark-submit my_snippet.py**

2) answer to ipython notebook question:
in my ipython notebook personal configuration the following lines doesn't exists:

```
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors', 5)
sc = SparkContext(appName="tmp", conf=conf)
```

"sc" is defined outside the scope of my program

3) Answer to question regarding numpy (or other module which needs to be installed)
In order to use numpy, you need to install numpy (using apt-get or pip or install from sources) on **every node in your cluster**.

Comment: you are right, running with `spark-submit` does solve the problem in the case of a stand-alone program. If, on the other hand, I want to run an IPython notebook, this won't work. I can start IPython with `IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook " pyspark` but then I can't change `SparkContext` options during the runtime (can I?). Moreover, if, instead of `pyspark`, the function uses `numpy` or any other module, `spark-submit` won't help either