# Using Spark and Python in same IDE

Tags: python, pyspark, anaconda, spyder

I am using Spyder(Anaconda) on Mac for Python development. I also have installed PySpark on my machine, which i use from the terminal. Is it possible to use both of them in Spyder, or somehow manage to import the spark context into my python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible just install

```
pip install findspark
```

then run

```
findspark.init()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763240

then try to import pyspark if it works then good or else
add pyspark to pythonpath & try again

```
# Add the PySpark classes to the Python path:
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
```