# Running pySpark in Jupyter notebooks - Windows

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter

I would like to run pySpark from Jupyter notebook. I downloaded and installed Anaconda which had Juptyer. I created the following lines

```
 from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
 conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
 sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-98c83f0bd5ff> in <module>()
  ----> 1 from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
  2 conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
  3 sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

 C:\software\spark\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\__init__.py in   <module>()
 39 
 40 from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
  ---> 41 from pyspark.context import SparkContext
 42 from pyspark.rdd import RDD
 43 from pyspark.files import SparkFiles

 C:\software\spark\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\context.py in <module>()
 26 from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
 27 
 ---> 28 from pyspark import accumulators
 29 from pyspark.accumulators import Accumulator
 30 from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast

 ImportError: cannot import name accumulators
```

I tried adding the following environment variable PYTHONPATH which points to the spark/python  directory, based on an answer in Stackoverflow  [importing pyspark in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell)

but this was of no help

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
import os
import sys

spark_path = "D:\spark"

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_path
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = spark_path

sys.path.append(spark_path + "/bin")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/pyspark/")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip")

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext("local", "test")
```

To verify:

```
In [2]: sc
Out[2]: <pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x707ccf8>
```

Comment: Nope. I get the following error  ImportError                               
---> 41 from pyspark.context import SparkContext
     42 from pyspark.rdd import RDD
     43 from pyspark.files import SparkFiles

C:\software\spark\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\context.py in <module>()
     26 from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
     27 
---> 28 from pyspark import accumulators
     29 from pyspark.accumulators import Accumulator
     30 from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast

ImportError: cannot import name accumulators

Answer (score 2):

**2018 version**

INSTALL PYSPARK on Windows 10 
JUPYTER-NOTEBOOK With ANACONDA NAVIGATOR

### STEP 1

**Download Packages**

1) spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz [Download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

2) java jdk 8 version [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

3) Anaconda v 5.2 [Download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

4) scala-2.12.6.msi [Download](http://scala-2.12.6.msi)

5) hadoop v2.7.1[Download](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)

### STEP 2

MAKE SPARK FOLDER IN **C:/** DRIVE AND PUT EVERYTHING INSIDE IT 
[It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsTrv.png)

**NOTE : DURING INSTALLATION OF SCALA GIVE PATH OF SCALA  INSIDE SPARK FOLDER**

### STEP 3

NOW SET NEW WINDOWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

1. `HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark\hadoop`
2. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`
3. `SCALA_HOME=C:\spark\scala\bin`
4. `SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark\bin`
5. `PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe`
6. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe`
7. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook`
8. **NOW SELECT PATH OF SPARK** :

   Click on Edit and add New

   Add "**C:\spark\spark\bin**” to variable “Path” Windows

### STEP 4

- Make folder where you want to store Jupyter-Notebook outputs and files
- After that open Anaconda command prompt and **cd Folder name**
- then enter **Pyspark**

thats it your browser will pop up with Juypter localhost

### STEP 5

Check pyspark is working or not !

Type simple code and run it

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
a = Row(name = 'Vinay' , age=22 , height=165)
print("a: ",a)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Running pySpark in Jupyter notebooks - Windows**

JAVA8 : https://www.guru99.com/install-java.html

Anakonda : https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Pyspark in jupyter : https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/

```
import findspark

findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
data = [(1, "siva", 100), (2, "siva2", 200),(3, "siva3", 300),(4, "siva4", 400),(5, "siva5", 500)]
schema = ['id', 'name', 'sallary']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
```