# Spark Installation and Configuration on MacOS ImportError: No module named pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to configure apache-spark on MacOS. All the online guides ask to either download the spark tar and set up some env variables or to use `brew install apache-spark` and then setup some env variables.

Now I installed apache-spark using `brew install apache-spark`.
I run `pyspark` in terminal and I am getting a python prompt which suggests that the installation was successful.

Now when I try to do `import pyspark` into my python file, I'm facing error saying `ImportError: No module named pyspark`

The strangest thing I'm not able to understand is how is it able to start an REPL of pyspark and not able to import the module into python code.

I also tried doing `pip install pyspark` but it does not recognize the module either.

In addition to installing apache-spark with homebrew, I've set up following env variables.

```
if which java > /dev/null; then export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home); fi

if which pyspark > /dev/null; then
  export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/"
  export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"
fi
```

Please suggest what exactly is missing on my setup to run pyspark code on my local machine.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry I dont use MAC , but there is another way in linux beside above answer:

```
sudo ln -s $SPARK_HOME/python/pyspark /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Python will read module from /path/to/your/python/**site-packages** at last

Comment: This kind of worked but then it doesn't find py4j protocol. Gives following error. ```No module named py4j.protocol``` However, it did resolve the error of not finding ```pyspark``` module.

Comment: @KeyurGolani just pip install py4j

Comment: or find it in $SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip and unzip it  to site-packages

Comment: Ok. ```pip install py4j``` was giving installation error. However, I used ```easy_install py4j``` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33463702/3078330 and it worked fine. Just had to set ```export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip``` in addition. Thanks a lot @zhangtong

Answer (score 5):

pyspark module is not include in your python

Try this instead

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/"

sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip")

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf

except ImportError as e:
    print ("error importing spark modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)

sc = SparkContext('local[*]','PySpark')
```

---

if you don't want that, include them into your system `PATH`. And don't forget to include the python path.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH
```

Comment: This approach did work. However, I am looking for a more permanent solution where I don't have to write the three lines everytime. I also tried configuring the same three things in OS environment. But with that approach, it is still not able to detect the pyspark module.