# How to run pyspark with Django?

Tags: python, django, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm developing a web application retrieving data from data lake, the data is stored in HDFS and I want to use pyspark to perform some analysis. In other words we have a script within ipython notebook and we want to use it with Django. I see that pyspark is also available at [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark/2.1.1), so I installed it with pip and the same script is imported as `.py` file from notebook is running fine, when I run it as `python myscript.py` it works fine. Hence, it should also work fine if I import that script within Django. So, is it the correct method, or I will have to run `spark-submit myscript.py`? I want to use Spark in cluster mode.

Comment: Did you found the way to run it? I got stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @AshrithGande use findspark , https://github.com/minrk/findspark

Comment: @AshrithGande https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763240/2214674

Comment: I'm using findspark, but I cannot load my model `model = RandomForestRegressionModel.load('model/')` what I that spark-submit you mentioned?