# Python/django application not running with supervisord

Tags: python, django, supervisord

I am trying to run Python Django app via supervisor with below configuration file.

```
[program:test3]
command=python manage.py runserver
directory=/home/ubuntu/code/example/current/project/
stdout_logfile=/var/log/test3.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/test3.log
user=ubuntu
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/code/example/bin/",PROJECT_ENV="dev"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600e
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
```

After running I was able to see there are 2 python process running at the moment.

```
ubuntu   29853  0.1  2.0 354468 41196 ?        Sl   11:33   0:00 python manage.py runserver
ubuntu   29860  1.1  3.4 516944 69768 ?        Sl   11:33   0:04 /home/ubuntu/code/analytics/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

I have mentioned the log file under supervisord config file and was able to see the below error in "/var/log/test3.log".

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named pyspark.ml.evaluation
```

I have already fulfilled all pip requirements in the directory.

Any idea?

Comment: You know that `runserver` is NOT for production, do you ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Right now, I am testing it for dev environment. Also, I am trying to run it via gunicorn but also giving the same issue [Import error].

Comment: seems to be  issue with the pyspark  please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell

Comment: @NakulNarayanan I tried running >pyspark from the command line which doesn't work then I sourced the ~/.bashrc and pyspark works. After that I have restarted the supervisord but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the dependencies in a virtual environment?

If so, you also need execute the `python manage.py runserver` command with the environment activated.

I would create a simple script that activates the virtual environment and executes the command, and then, in supervisor, just run that script.

In your supervisor config file, change the command to:

```
command=/usr/local/bin/run_local_server.sh
```

Then, create the run_local_server.sh script which first activates the virtual environment and then executes the `python manage.py runserver` command.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
source env/bin/activate
cd project_folder
python manage.py runserver
```

Also, you can specify the pythonpath in supervisor: 
`pythonpath = '/opt/myenv/myproject'` if needed.

Comment: Hey, It is working when I am trying to run it from the login shell, I am getting issue while running it from the supervisord.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use virtual environment?

If that's the case, try using the `python` executable in the virtual environment.

i.e. change the line in the supervisor conf flie

`..path/to/virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver`

supervisor might execute the line with different user or in newly created shell process.
In either case, your VE python is not used, but systematically installed one is used.

Comment: what is the output of `..path/to/virtualenv/bin/python -c "import "pyspark"