# How to access SparkContext from SparkSession instance?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am importing `SparkSession` as follows in PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

Then I create `SparkSession`:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
```

and try to access `SparkContext`:

```
spark.SparkContext.broadcast(...)
```

However, I get an error that `SparkContext` does not exist. How can I access it in order to set `broadcast` variables?

Comment: Set pyspark as environment variable [help] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell)

Comment: @Prateek: That's not the question I am asking how to access SparkContext using `spark`, which is the instance of SparkSession.

Comment: `from pyspark import SparkContext as sc` if it doesnt work you have not set pyspark in environement variable OR spark server is not running

Comment: @Prateek: No, it will not work, because it should be related to the created SparkSession. I solved this problem myself just by `spark.sparkContext.broadcast(...)` instead of `spark.SparkContext.broadcast(...)`

Comment: great! I thought you are referring to sc in general

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You almost got it right, it's lowercase s at the beginning:

```
>>> spark.sparkContext
<SparkContext master=local[*] appName=PySparkShell>
```

Answer (score 5):

Asumming you have a spark session

```
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

---

Spark Context can be inferred using

```
spark_context = spark_session._sc
```

or

```
spark_context = spark_session.sparkContext
```