# How to install libraries to python in zeppelin-spark2 in HDP

Tags: python, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I am using HDP Version: 2.6.4

Can you provide a step by step instructions on how to install libraries to the following python directory under spark2 ?

The sc.version (spark version) returns

```
res0: String = 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
```

The spark2 interpreter name and value is as following

```
zeppelin.pyspark.python:    /usr/local/Python-3.4.8/bin/python3.4
```

The python version and current libraries are

```
%spark2.pyspark

import pip
import sys

sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])

print("--")     
print (sys.version)
print("--")
print(installed_packages_list)

--
3.4.8 (default, May 30 2018, 11:05:04) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)]
--
['pip==9.0.1', 'setuptools==28.8.0']
```

### Update 1: `using pip install [package name]` actually leads to two problems

1) The HDP is pointing at python2.6 rather than python3.4.8

2) pip3 is not there for some reason

Therefore, I am thinking of installing miniconda and pointing Zeppelin there and installing all the packages in conda to prevent conflict between python 2.6 and 3.4.8

Comment: Use `python3 -m pip install <package>`. https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open your terminal and type `pip` and press the TAB key. The pip versions available on your sandbox shall be listed. Use **pip3** to install the packages you require. The way to do so remains the same `pip3 install "packageName"`. This would make the package available with the Python3 installation you wish to use in Zeppelin.

Comment: thanks again for trying to help. Kindly check the updated part of the quesiton

Answer (score 3):

This was painful for us. The workaround that works is:

1. Install the python packages you need from the terminal using `pip` or `pip3` accordingly.
2. By default the `zeppelin.pyspark.python` on the spark interpreter is set to: python. This python did not recognize the packages we had installed using the terminal. We had to update `zeppelin.pyspark.python` : **/usr/bin/python** (the path to the python command, you can get it using the command 'which python')

Now the interpreter and zeppelin notebooks were able to access all the packages we installed from the terminal.

Comment: I just pointed my spark interpreter's `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` vars to `python3` and that was enough. Assumes python3 is in the PATH