# Zeppelin Notebook no module named pandas and matplotlib

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, anaconda, apache-zeppelin

Hello guys,

My question is about zeppelin notebook. I am new to zeppelin environment. I have a AWS account. I am working on EMR cluster. I want to use pandas and matplotlib in zeppelin environment.  But, I got the error no module named pandas and matplotlib.  I find [this](https://dziganto.github.io/zeppelin/spark/zeppelinhub/emr/anaconda/tensorflow/shiro/s3/theano/bootstrap%20script/EMR-From-Scratch/) tutorial. I came to Step 8 but, i stil do not get the same problem. 
Zeppelin has interpreter. I try to change python path even if i am sure the path, i still got the same error. [This link mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599469/using-python-with-zeppelin-under-the-spark-2-interpreter)
If anyone experience about these issues, please help me.

```
%pyspark
import os
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib

print("Numpy "+numpy.__version__)
print("Pandas "+pandas.__version__)
print("Matplotlib "+matplotlib.__version__)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-444747300595843376.py", line 367, in <module>
raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-444747300595843376.py", line 355, in <module>
exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Comment: can you share the traceback? maybe there is more clues there. Also can you share the bootstrap file?

Comment: I shared my traceback.

Comment: This is probably wrong python is used. please check `zeppelin.pyspark.python` in interpreter setting. You can set it as the python path which python you would like to use

Comment: I know interpreter setting. I mentioned above. I changed zeppelin.pyspark.python and I am sure the path, i still got the same error.

Comment: Can you run the following code to verify whether the python version running is correct ? `import sys              print(sys.version)`

Comment: Hi zjffdu, I am getting this output " 2.7.13 (default, Jan 31 2018, 00:17:36) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I am pulling the path from my EC2 machine. I enter my SSH into my Master node on AWS. I install pandas and matplotib. Then run the “which python” command on that instance. After that, i copied to pyspark.python path. Finally, it worked.