# Pyspark: python packages on the executor server

Tags: pyspark

I just started working with Pyspark on new application..
I installed with pip all the packages(dependencies of my application) that I needed in the server that run spark-submit.
Do i have to install the python packages of my application on the other spark gateways?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importing pyspark in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell)

Comment: I could not find answer to my question on this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the packages on all worker nodes. You could use [cssh](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-multiple-linux-servers-clusterssh%20cssh) to make your life a bit easier.

An alternative to installing every pip package in advance is to use a requirements.txt (and preferentially an virtualenvironment). To use a requirements.txt just launch spark-submit with the following parameters:

```
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true  
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=native 
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.requirements=/Users/jzhang/github/spark/requirements.txt 
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/Users/jzhang/anaconda/bin/virtualenv 
--conf spark.pyspark.python=/usr/local/bin/python3 spark_virtualenv.py
```

Please find further information at [2](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/104947/using-virtualenv-with-pyspark.html%202).